# How do I use VB.NET to send an email from an Outlook account?

Tags: vb.net, email

I'm trying to send an email via an outlook email account through a vb.net program. When I run the code I get an error telling me that I don't have a secure connection. I've been searching online and have tried all the adjustments I've found but I'm still not having any luck.

Here is my code at the moment(*specific email addresses and passwords are changed*):

```
Private Sub LEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LEmail.Click
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.com")
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("sample@outlook.com", "Password")
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("sample@outlook.com")
        mail.To.Add("recipient@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from OUTLOOK"
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MessageBox.Show("mail sent")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

EDIT: I've also tried SmtpServer.Port = 25

EDIT 2: Error message reads:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpExeption: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM as System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Sent(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at WindowsApplication.Form1.LEmail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Current\Visual Studio\WindowsApplication\Form1.vb:line 553

EDIT 3: Second Error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; We noticed some unusual activity in your Hotmail account. To help protect you, we've temporarily blocked your account. at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse) at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args) at System.Net.CloseableStream.Close() at System.Net.MailWriter.Close() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at WindowsApplication.Form1.LEmail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\User\Monica\Documents\Current\Visual Studio\WindowsApplication\Form1.vb:line 553

Comment: Have you tried what i suggested below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the smtpserver from `smtp.outlook.com` to `smtp-mail.outlook.com`

web.config settings

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yourname@outlook.com">
    <network host="smtp-mail.outlook.com" userName="yourname@outlook.com" password="passwordhere" port="587" enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: That helped, my program actually reaches the email server now :) The server itself won't allow me access though

Comment: What's the error? It may be a password error. Personally I like to put the settings in my web.config under  <system.net>. I'll modify my answer to reflect it.

Comment: LOL! well, the error is not in the code. You probably hit the mail server so many times they think your are a spammer! I think correcting the smtp server fixed the problem, now you will have to have your account reset by outlook (I believe they send an email to your alternate email address informing you)

Comment: I posted the second error in Edit 3. I've triple check the password and it works to manually log in. I'll try putting the settings in web.config like you suggested

Comment: I got an email from Outlook: 
"Hello Monica,
To continue sending messages, please sign in and validate your Outlook.com account.
This helps us stop automated programs from sending junk email.
Thanks for your help and patience!
The Outlook.com Team"
I've signed in again but still hitting the same error, do I need to give them time to resolve it?
Thank you so much for your help though, you're a treasure :)

Comment: Yeah, I would wait. You may have to contact them if it persists. Sometimes they will flag the ip address as a bot trying to spam, but I think your program problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false
```

before this line:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("sample@outlook.com", "Password")
```

[Whoever designed this API obviously wasn't thinking like a consumer!]

Comment: I rearranged it like you suggested but not I'm getting an error message telling me that my mailbox is unavailable due to unusual activity. Are there perhaps some settings within my email account that I need to change?

Comment: which is a different error to the one in the original question.

Comment: Just posted it in Edit 3